# Типы данных в php

Tags: php

Данные хранятся в таком виде: `{"date":1634489656,"nom":2,"admin":"STEAM_0"}`.
Необходимо вытащить дату. Подскажите пожалуйста, как?

Comment: Это json. "php json" - такой запрос даст вам много вариантов. Дойдет дело до кода, будут ошибки, возвращайтесь

Comment: Ну и дата выражена как число секунд после `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`

Answer (score 0):

C помощью **[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)**  и ассоциативного массива

```
$result = json_decode($str, true)['date'];
```

Comment: А если так `$result = json_decode($str)->date`?

Comment: Можно. Просто людям проще работать с массивами и объяснять что такое `->` будет ещё дольше. и если есть массивы, то потом надо будет объяснять почему `->0`  не работает..крч. больше проблем